# Screen-sharing and Touch ID

Tags: macos, screen-sharing, sudo

On macOS Monterey I would like to use sudo without password by using Touch ID while sharing my screen during a Zoom call.

I added  `auth sufficient pam_tid.so` to `/etc/pam.d/sudo` and it works fine while not sharing the screen.

But sometimes I have the bad habit to write my password in plaintext to the terminal. So I would be really happy if there is a way to make it work with screen-sharing.

Comment: any news on this?

Comment: Same issue. I suspect this is happening because screen sharing is also used for tech support, and the remote IT technician needs to be able to type in the password since they don't have physical access to the machine. 

Really annoying because I use touch ID a lot and having to go to a password manager to look up my password while screensharing is not at all good.